# convert string to datetime with form yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert this `2014-01-01 23:00:00` to `DateTime` I have done like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2014-01-01 23:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and the result was like this :

```
1/1/2014 11:00:00 PM
```

this thing drive me crazy because this format was working in java.

Comment: Did you get this result by calling the ToString method?

Comment: does simply using `DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01 23:00:00")` not give you your expected DateTime?

Comment: You're not using a format string in your output, only in your input.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The `DateTime` parsed successfully. At that point, it doesn't *have* a format. You then (via `WriteLine`) forcefully converted it back into a string in whatever format the default is.

Comment: See e.g. the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx): "Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D... "

Comment: Don't use ParseExact. Use instead Parse or TryParse. without specifying the colture.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think your parsing worked. The problem is when converting back to string. You can provide the desired format in parameter :

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2010-01-01 23:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
```

By default (without a specified format), it uses formatting information derived from the current culture.

Comment: can you tell the compiler to use the parsed format and not fallback to current culture.

Comment: @danarj - sure, by using either the overload of `ToString` that takes an `IFormatProvider` or the one that takes a `string`.

Comment: @danarj - at the point that you have it as a `DateTime` value, then as per my comments, what we have is a structure that counts the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since midnight on 01/01/0001 and what type (Local, UTC or unspecified) it is. It doesn't "remember" how it was created.

Comment: You can't. Look at Jon Skeet's answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407499/set-datetime-format

Answer (score 8):

Because `2014-01-01 23:00:00` IS `2014-01-01 11:00:00 PM`.

**Better explanation**

You are implicitly calling `DateTime.ToString()`, which by default uses the General (`"G"`) format, which in the `en-US` culture is  `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`.

If you want to display the time in a different format, you need to specify it:

```
string s = DateTime.ParseExact("2010-01-01 23:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Or since you're using the same format string,  just store it:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2010-01-01 23:00:00", format , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString(format));
```

Comment: what if there is microsecond or a milli second field as well?

Comment: @Raulp Then add it to your format string. Something like `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"` depending on how precise you want to be.