# Bind string to Date Picker selected date in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have a sting which I converted to Date Format of type (dd/mm/yyyy) as `15/08/2016 11:00:00 AM`

I want to bind this to Datetime Picker Selected Date as follows

```
var MyDate= "15/08/2016 11:00:00 AM";
DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDate,"dd/mm/yyyy",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If I do

```
 DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

This works perfectly. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407499/set-datetime-format

Comment: I have already used this one. This is not working in my case.

Comment: Change ''mm' (minutes) to 'MM' (months).

Comment: @jdweng I used like this `DateTime.ParseExact("15/08/2016 11:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: You mean you want to change the date format of datePicker right ?

Comment: @UmairFarooq yes exactly.

Comment: Can you clarify where is the problem exactly? Your top example throws "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Is this the problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: @Cyferka : Yes I want to assign a string date format to Date Picker selected date.

Comment: You can use this: DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse("15/08/2016 11:00:00 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); and set the formatting in xaml (Umair Farooq answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a style for `DatePickerTextBox`

In your Window, before start of `<Grid>`, use this code to define a style for `DatePickerTextBox`

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
         Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/mm/yyyy', 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

In the above code, the line you should be concerned about is

```
Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/mm/yyyy'
```

If you see, you can define a string format for the text that appears in this `DatePickerTextBox`.

Now you should run the code version in which you use only

```
DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

this line of code rather than the other three statements. This code should format the string in a format you specified in the above line of code.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("15/08/2016 11:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I added **tt** for AM/PM formatting

**EDIT:**

```
<DatePickerTextBox Text="{Binding Date1, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt'}"></DatePickerTextBox>
```

Comment: He already knows how to format the object of DateTime. He wants to format the date that appears in DatePickerTextBox

Comment: I case you have not checked, all his code examples like (var MyDate= "15/08/2016 11:00:00 AM";
DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDate,"dd/mm/yyyy",
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);) are crashing, it's invalid formatting, so I am assuming here is the first issue that has to be fixed.

Comment: He said with DateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now, this works perfectly So I assumed he will run the code in answer provided by me with this code. Because with this he will get the desired result he is wanting in the question.

Comment: Well, I will ask him where is the problem exactly, because I see the problem is C# code for sure.

Comment: Sure. The format of datePicker is by default and to change it, you have to define style rather than formatting underlying bound DateTime Object

Comment: Yes, tested it, totally agree with you, edited my answer, you can also just set String Format

Comment: Yes but there is no control to be used as DatePickerTextBox. It is enclosed in DatePicker. So you have to set style to edit its behavior. And that is what I did

Comment: There is DatePickerTextBox, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datepickertextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes there is. But I guess if you use just this then you won't be able to pick a date.