# Why DateTime dd/MM/yyyy does not changing to yyyy-MM-dd?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to change a DateTime `dd/MM/yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` but I can't do it, the DateTime just doesn't changing and I don't know why it is happening.

How could I do this ?

**Trying**

```
DateTime d1 = g.app_data ?? DateTime.Now.Date; // 2/19/2020
string _dtFormat = d1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");  //2020-02-19
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(_dtFormat);       //converting should be 2020-02-19 as DateTime

//print values 
Debug.WriteLine("Original: " + g.app_data);
Debug.WriteLine("D1: " + d1);
Debug.WriteLine("DT_Format: " + _dtFormat);
Debug.WriteLine("D2: " + d2);
```

**Output**

```
Original: 2/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
D1: 2/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
DT_Format: 2020-02-19
D2: 2/19/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a format (what you see in the watch window is a *formatted string representation*). When you parse it back, it's a `DateTime` again. The input format is lost.

Comment: `DateTime` is a number, its as simple as that, convert it to string and back all you like, its still a number and a number and has no format, internally its stored like this `private UInt64 dateData;` if you want a format, format it when converting it to string

Comment: ‵Debug.WriteLine("D2: " + d2);` means write `d2` in default `DateTime` format.

Comment: DateTime formatting is only relevant when turning into a string. You can't change how it's stored. That would be like thinking you can change a decimal value of 0.12345 to change to .12 just because you formatted it as `.ToString(".00");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set DateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407499/set-datetime-format)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: This way I know, but as I asked in this post I need that it change the DateTime itself to `yyyy-MM-dd` and doesn't the string format.

Comment: And as all the comments stated, you can't do that.